# Limit has no effect on aggregation

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables:

```
users:
id 
------
1

permissions:
id | action | userId
---|--------|--------
 1 |  read  |    1
 2 |  write |    1
```

When I run the following query (return users with its permissions):

```
select
    users.*,
    (string_agg(permissions.action::text, ',') as permissions
from
    "users"
join "permissions" "permissions" on
    "userId" = "users"."id"
    and "userId" = 1
group by
    "users"."id"
order by
    "users"."id" asc
limit 1
```

I get:

```
id | permissions
---|-------------
 1 |  read,write
```

Which is great (this is what I need) but I expected it to return:

```
id | permissions
---|-------------
 1 |  read
```

Because of the query has `limit 1` constraint.
Anyone can shed some light on what happens in the background?

Comment: Use lateral correlated subquery instead of `permissions` table with proper ordering and limiting.

Answer (score 1):

`LIMIT` is applied late in the query, after aggregation, so you get the complete first group.

You should apply the `LIMIT` in a lateral subquery:

```
SELECT users.*, p.action
FROM users
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT permissions.action
                       FROM permissions
                       WHERE permissions."userId" = users.id
                       ORDER BY permissions.id
                       LIMIT 1) AS p
WHERE users.id = 1;
```

And alternative is the non-standard `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (users.id)
       users.*, p.action
FROM users
   JOIN permissions AS p
      ON p."userId" = users.id
WHERE users.id = 1;
ORDER BY users.id, permissions.id
LIMIT 1;
```